# Relation between train and test MSE in case of low Variance

Tags: machine-learning, variance, bias-variance-tradeoff

maybe that is a dublicate, but I cant find an answer on my specific question. I am thinking about the bias-variance trade-off. It is known that, if I have a large variance but low bias I am overfitting. This picture is a bit confusing for me then:
[image]

As we can see: If the flexibility is higher (higher variance in Terms of a more complex model) the training MSE (Grey curve) is decreasing. In Terms of the decomposition of the train MSE into

$MSE_{train}=Bias^2+Var$

I cant figure out how the Train MSE can fall if the variance is increasing with the model flexibility